# Pegando o Nome e ID do Dropdown

Tags: javascript

Tenho este JavaScript que seta os valores ao DropDown:

```
$('#Estado').change(function () {
var id = $(Estado).val();

    $(function buscarCidade() {
        //alert(id);
        var url = '@Url.Action("SelecaoCidade", "Chamada")';//url do controller que passará a informação
        $.post(url, { id: id },

             function (data) {//Caso o retorno dê certo
                 //window.alert(data.length);
                 $('#Cidade').children().remove();
                 if (data.length > 0) {
                     $.each(data, function (index, value) {
                         $('#Cidade').append('<option value="' + value.Id + '">' + value.Nome + '</option>');
                     });
                 } else {
                     var novaOpcao = $('<option value=""></option>');
                     $('#Cidade').append(newOption);
                 }//fim if else

             });//fim do post

    });//BuscarCidade

});//Estado
```

Eu preciso pegar o nome e ID das cidades que foram inseridas, e tentei utilizar estes trechos de código pra pegar o id, mas não rolou:

> var idCid = Cidade.value;
>
> var idCid = $(Cidade).val();
>
> var idCid = Cidade.index;

Comment: $("#Estado").attr("id"); Veja se assim consegue.

Comment: Acredito que simplesmente por: `var idCid = $('#Cidade').attr("id"); ` e `var nome = $('#Cidade').attr("name");

Comment: Ocorre algum erro? Qual o valor do parâmetro "data"? Ele realmente é um objecto que contém as propriedades "Id" e "Nome"? Faça um `console.log(data);` e poste o resultado aqui.

Comment: DouglasGarrido e LucasCosta o attr("id") me exibiu apenas 'Cidade' (não o nome da cidade), porém o attr("name") deu undefined

Comment: @FilipeMoraes não sei se está certo, mas obtive estes dados: **nenhum elemento encontrado  abort:1:1
O método getPreventDefault() não deve mais ser usado. No lugar, use defaultPrevented.  browserLink:37:40278
ReferenceError: data is not defined[Learn More]  Votar:226:33**

Comment: Esta é a resposta do Json: **[{"CidadeID":1,"Nome":"Aparecida","EstadoID":25,"Estado":null,"Locais":null},{"CidadeID":2,"Nome":"Guaratinguet
á","EstadoID":25,"Estado":null,"Locais":null},{"CidadeID":3,"Nome":"Roseira","EstadoID":25,"Estado":null
,"Locais":null},{"CidadeID":4,"Nome":"Lorena","EstadoID":25,"Estado":null,"Locais":null},{"CidadeID"
:5,"Nome":"Taubaté","EstadoID":25,"Estado":null,"Locais":null},{"CidadeID":6,"Nome":"Caçapava","EstadoID"
:25,"Estado":null,"Locais":null}]**

Comment: Então Fábio. O json não possui a propriedade "Id" e sim "CidadeID". No seu código, onde tens value.Id troque por value.CidadeID

Comment: Show de Bola @FilipeMoraes Valeu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pelo que li nos cometários, o `json` enviado como resposta a requisição `POST`  não possui a propriedade `id` e sim `CidadeID`, então no seu código basta substituir onde tens:

```
value.id
```

Por:

```
value.CidadeID
```

Assim será atribuído o id corretamente a cada `option`.

Answer (score 1):

Para pegar os valores do select você pode usar:

```js
$("#cidade").change(function(){
  var idCid = $(this).attr("id")
    , valor = $(this).val()
    , nome = $(this).attr("name");
  console.log(idCid, nome, valor);  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="cidade" name="cidade">
  <option value="">Selecione</option>
  <option value="SP">São Paulo</option>
  <option value="CT">Curitiba</option>
</select>
```

Comment: pelo exemplo que me deu aparece isto: **Cidade** _undefined_ **undefined**

Comment: Provavelmente você não deve possuir o atributo `name` e qual o valor de `value.Id` quando você faz append no select?

Comment: pelo que vi (alert(value.Id)), está vindo undefined